# python re.findall doesn't match duplicates

Tags: python, regex, findall

Let's assume the input is like this. Actually it's longer, but for the sake of clarity, I'll leave it like this.

> Valid from: Wed Mar 05 15:40:45 GMT+00:00 2014 until: **Thu Jan 05 08:28:29 GMT+00:00 2034**
>   Valid from: Fri Jan 10 08:28:29 GMT+00:00 2014 until: **Thu Jan 05 08:28:29 GMT+00:00 2034**

Here's my code:

```
 certDataArray = []
            patterns = ['Alias name:\s(.*)\n', 'Owner:\s(.*)\n', 'Issuer:\s(.*)\n', 'Serial number:\s(.*)\n', 'Valid from:\s(.*) until', 'until:\s(.*)\n']
            for pattern in patterns:
                result = re.compile(pattern)
                result = result.findall(cmd)
                certDataArray.append(result)
            certDataArray = zip(certDataArray[0],certDataArray[1],certDataArray[2],certDataArray[3],certDataArray[4],certDataArray[5])
```

Now, the problem is that findall will not match the second match for the pattern "until:\s(.*)\n" because there's an identical match already. Not sure if I phrased it correctly, but you get the idea.

I've been googling solutions and found 2:

1) Use the new improved python regex module. This is off the table, because I'm not running this on my PC, this code will be running in an enterprise level platform. Upgrading python in any way is unlikely and I don't suppose I can just copy-paste regex.py into the server to make the python over there use it, or can I? I downloaded the package and it seems that it requires installation, which I am not allowed to undertake on this system.

2) re.iterate. Been looking at it, and quite frankly I don't understand how it works

I also tried to break down the string into lines and use "for" to loop through each line, but this seems like a retarded method that can backfire heavily.

All ideas are very much welcome, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't because it's a duplicate match - the second line *doesn't* end with `'\n'`. You should really be using:

- `r"raw strings"` to prevent the escapes from messing up;
- the regex end-of-string marker `$` rather than `\n`; and
- the `re.MULTILINE` option to treat each line separately.

For example:

```
>>> s = """Valid from: Wed Mar 05 15:40:45 GMT+00:00 2014 until: Thu Jan 05 08:28:29 GMT+00:00 2034
Valid from: Fri Jan 10 08:28:29 GMT+00:00 2014 until: Thu Jan 05 08:28:29 GMT+00:00 2034"""
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r'until:\s(.*)$', s, re.MULTILINE)
['Thu Jan 05 08:28:29 GMT+00:00 2034', 'Thu Jan 05 08:28:29 GMT+00:00 2034']
```

Comment: Yes indeed, if re.MULTILINE is added to re.compile(pattern, re.MULTILINE), and $ used instead of \n, then it works. I still don't completely understand what multiline does, however. Can you explain?
Also, when is it required to put the letter 'r' in front of the pattern and when not?

Comment: I don't understand why I need to treat each line separately in this case, if the pattern I'm trying to match doesn't run on several lines, it doesn't start on one, and end on another line.

Comment: Yes, but you want to match the end of the string **or the end of a line** using `$`, and if you don't use `re.MULTILINE` that only matches the end of the string, so you're back to getting one result.

Comment: Oh, right. In the last line, there's nothing to match because the line doesn't end with anything that would match $. You just saved me from rewriting atleast 1 days of work. Thanks a lot!